# Get current frame on Microsoft Maps MapTileSource.Play()

Tags: uwp-maps

I have a MapTileSource which I .Play() on Microsoft Maps. This works well, but I'm wondering how I can get the current frame. I'm not able to find an event or anything.

Basically, there is 10 layers. I would like to display the date for each layer as it's played. For example: Layer 1: Monday XX/XX/XXXX. Layer 2: Tuesday XX/XX/XXXX.

Does anyone have any recommendations how I can fire an event each time a new frame is Played on the map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's any way to do this. The best workaround I can suggest is to estimate the right label to show based on the frame timing you requested, and then periodically stop and restart the animation to remove any drift.